# Command and Conquer Shockwave, where are the costs of the armies stored?

Tags: mods, cheats, command-and-conquer-zero-hour, command-and-conquer-shockwave

In Command and Conquer Generals: Zero Hour, the armies costs, build time, etc . are stored in the file INIZH.big , so if you modify them you can change the building costs, building time, etc,  of soldiers, tanks, etc. Now I want to do the same for the mod Shockwave, which apparently uses the same folder for installation (the executable file is installed in the Command and Conquer Generals: Zero hour folder), but I dont know which file I have to modify for changing the building costs, apparently modifying the original INIZH.big from Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour doesnt affect the mod.

Then, where are the costs of the armies stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, if anyone is interested is file !Shw_ini.gib , and inside it's just like INIZH.big from Command and Conquer Generals: Zero Hour .

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is ever wanting to modify the build costs for a single map, instead of the entire game/mod install, they can use the following in the map's `Map.INI` file.

```
PlayerTemplate FactionAmerica
  ProductionCostChange = AmericaCommandCenter -90% ;Reduce Cost
  ProductionCostChange = AmericaVehicleDozer  90% ;Adds Cost
  ProductionTimeChange = AmericaCommandCenter -100% ; Reduce Buildtime
  ProductionTimeChange = AmericaVehicleDozer 500% ; Add Buildtime
End
```

You'll need to replace the object names and faction name for whichever Shockwave faction and unit you want to modify.

The Map.INI file doesn't exist by default. You need to make it yourself by navigating to the folder for the map you're working on, usually in %UserProfile%\Documents\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour Data\Maps\ and create a new Map.INI file.

Map.INI allows simple mods to be made for a specific map, instead of needing to mod the whole game. The INI settings listed above can reduce the cost and/or build time. This tutorial from cnclabs about making weather for a map has some good Map.INI info https://www.cnclabs.com/maps/generals/worldbuilder/tutorials/adding-weather-effects.aspx

Credit to Adriane and NLS for finding these INI values. No one knew this was possible for two decades.

Comment: Is the cost of building the Command Center/Dozer reduced with that command? Also where do you find the Map.INI file?

Comment: The Map.INI file doesn't exist by default. You need to make it yourself by navigating to the folder for the map you're working on, usually in `%UserProfile%\Documents\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour Data\Maps\ ` and create a new Map.INI file. `Map.INI` allows simple mods to be made for a specific map, instead of needing to mod the whole game

Yes, you can reduce the cost and/or build time with those settings. This tutorial from cnclabs about making weather for a map has some good `Map.INI` info https://www.cnclabs.com/maps/generals/worldbuilder/tutorials/adding-weather-effects.aspx

Comment: thanks for sharing that info. I think editing it into your answer could be useful.

Comment: Good feedback. Thank you, I updated my answer to include info about `map.ini`